# Breaking out Quantity

Tags: vba, excel

I've never set up a macro before but I have seen one where it views the "Quantity" column on a spreadsheet and takes anything that isn't a quantity of (1) and duplicates the entry the number of times listed in the "Quantity" column.

Could someone tell me how I can set that up?

Comment: Paul - could you show a snapshot of how your data is organised in the s/sheet please? And if possible, the desired output...

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that may help you get started. I am assuming you want something like the following:

```
      Col A    Col B                  Col A    Col B
1     Item     Quantity               Item     Quantity
2     Apple    1                      Apple    1
3     Orange   2                      Orange
4     Banana   1              ----->  Orange   2
5     Pear     4                      Banana   1
6     Grape    2                      Pear
7                                     Pear
8                                     Pear
9                                     Pear     4
10                                    Grape    
11                                    Grape    2
```

This can be achieved with the following code:

```
Sub ExpandItem()
    Dim lastRow As Long, rngQuantity As Range, rw As Long

    lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    For rw = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(rw, 1) > 1 Then
            AddItem Cells(rw, 1), Cells(rw, 1).Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub

Sub AddItem(item As Range, quantity As Long)
    Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To (quantity - 1)
               item.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
               item.Offset(-1, 0) = item.Value
        Next i
End Sub
```

Hope this helps get you moving in the right direction